# What is difference between STM32 timer channels with N suffix?

Tags: stm32

For instance in cubeIDE for board L432KC for TIM16 I can select `PWM Generation CH2` and `PWM Generation CH2N`. What is the difference? Do they need to be interface differently?

I.e. `HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);` will work for CH2N?

Answer (score 2):

N are inverted outputs.

To generate a differential signal, use both the normal and the inverted output of the same channel.

Comment: So I assume N output is inverted.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the complementary, it makes it very easy to define a deadtime between the 2 signals (there's a deadtime parameter to specify the deadtime between the 2 complementary outputs).